# How to change speed cap of libgdx bodies

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I've noticed that there is a limit to how fast one of my box2d bodies can move (2 meters per tick), is there a way I could increase this cap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `World.setVelocityThreshold(1000000.0f);` to increase the the limit, but **this can lead to other problems**.
A better alternative is to reduce the size of the world, so the limit of 2 meters per calculation step is sufficient.

[This answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/48000/143689) describes the problems when increasing the velocity threshold and describes other possible solutions to this kind of problem.